# Need an older version of apache commons lang3 in Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I need an older version of Apache Commons Lang3 in Azure Artifacts. I need version 3.8.1 (last version that supports Java 7) but it's not listed. Is there a way to get Azure Artifacts to grab a specific version from Maven Central?

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue, have your check my answer? does it answer your question?

Comment: Hi - I am still unable to get version 3.8.1 in Azure Artifacts. Would you be able to provide an example with Java 7 and commons-lang3 version 3.8.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating a new access token for the settings file and it worked. No where in the logs did it indicate there was an error connecting to the Artifacts feed. It just quietly rolled over to grab everything from Central.

Answer (score -1):

Since the package is public, you just need at least one time to use, and then the package version will be listed in the artifact feed.

It is successfully to get the specific version package on my side:

[image]

> How I achieve that:

**POM.xml** on my side：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>111</version>

  <name>demo</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>BowmanCP</id>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_packaging/BowmanCP/maven/v1</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>BowmanCP</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_packaging/BowmanCP/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

The key is 3 part:

***1, repositories part***

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>BowmanCP</id>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_packaging/BowmanCP/maven/v1</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

***2, distributionManagement part***

```
  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>BowmanCP</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/BowmanCP/_packaging/BowmanCP/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

***3, dependencies part***

```
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

The previous 2 part comes from this place:

[image]

[image]

Push this Maven project to a repo in Azure DevOps, and then use below yml to install the package:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0 # This step is changing the setting.xml in agent account.
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'BowmanCP'
- task: Maven@3 #This step will install the specific maven package mentioned in POM.xml, 
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'demo/pom.xml'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

This is my repo structure:

[image]

You can refer to this official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/maven/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

Comment: I see in the build log: Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.pom  BUT this version does NOT get put in Azure Artifacts and the build fails.

Comment: I have posted this as an issue in the microsoft docs as well: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12718